Unable to access HTTPS domain within local network, but HTTP works
I have an Apache webserver listening on ports 80 and 443. Port forwarding has been configured on the router to forward traffic from the public IP address on these ports to the internal IP address hosting the Apache web server.
I have set up a virtual host in Apache and activated HTTPS on port 443. I have a domain that points to the public IP address through a DNS A record.
I can reach this domain via HTTP on port 80 from within the local network, and externally over the internet.
However, accessing the domain via HTTPS on port 443 is only possible externally over the internet. The request to open the domain via HTTPS when connected to the same network as the Apache web server times out.
After researching, I noticed many people mentioned this being an issue with DNS and NAT. Apparently, you cannot reach a domain pointing to the external IP address of a network, while being within the same network unless you have your own DNS server and configure it accordingly to return the correct IP address based on where the request is coming from.
If so, how is it that I can reach the domain name when on the same network over HTTP? Why is only HTTPS affected?
I don't have any firewall running.

... unless you have your own DNS server and configure it accordingly to return the correct IP address based on where the request is coming from. no, that's not necessary - does your router allow NAT hairpinning (aka NAT loopback or NAT reflection) - seems it does if port 80 works

@JaromandaX I looked through the settings but didn't find anything that suggested it supports that. The router model is Hitron CODA-4582.

but port 80 works ... according to you

@JaromandaX That's why I'm perplexed. How is this possible and what could be the reason why?

your port forward is different for 80 vs 443?

@JaromandaX I have 2 rules which are identical except for the ports. One for 80 and one for 443.
